# How can I track user location continuously in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I want to track user location. For this reason, I am using location package of flutter. Likewise, I am using Streams to track in real-time. but how can I show user location on the Google Maps in real time. I have some problem about showing real-time location on Google Maps.

** Here is my Location Service class **

```
class LocationService {

 UserLocation _currentLocationofUser;

 Location location = Location();

 //Sürekli güncelle
 StreamController<UserLocation> _locationController =
     StreamController<UserLocation>.broadcast();

 LocationService() {
   location.requestPermission().then((granted) {
     if (granted != null) {
       location.onLocationChanged.listen((locationData) {
         if (locationData != null) {
           _locationController.add(UserLocation(
               latitude: locationData.latitude,
               longitude: locationData.longitude));
         }
       });
     }
   });
 }

 Stream<UserLocation> get locationStream => _locationController.stream;
```

** Here is my main class to show real-time location of user **

```
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var userLocation = Provider.of<UserLocation>(context);

    return GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          zoom: 12,
          target: LatLng(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude)),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _mapController = controller;
      },
    );
  }


}
```